# internet security activex problem

Tags: security, activex

Could anybody tell me what can cause such a problem:

I have made group policy for users and allowed their IE to use activex and so on.

Those users are working on our server. So there is one user who has the same rights as all has, however, when he enters IE and tries to open application there it gives an error: ACTIVEX is not allowed on you browser. I made another user for him with the same rules etc. and it works.

Where is the bug? It happens almost every time with some of our users after server restart.

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Some more information would help. Are you using AXIS to allow ActiveX? What is the OS? Have you tried the Group Policy Results Wizard to se if there is something you've missed?

Comment: Windows is the OS. No i do not tried wizard. The mystics is that all other have access but this user does not... they all have the same rules!